# CouchDB: Get all Documents by key:value

Tags: python, couchdb

I am a newb to CouchDB, so please excuse my ignorance.

Here is what a document looks like stored in my collection:

```
{
   "_id": "95e05530b594bf6b7fc5ef139e44abc1",
   "_rev": "1-b583386c66b5c1b705cecacb2ea5c435",
   "status": "active",
   "account_id": 1050004,
   "workflow": "{'hello': 'world'}"
}
```

I need to get all documents where `account_id` is equal to 1050004 (or any other `account_id` passed in). I just can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: As of being a key value storage this whole document is indexed under one key. If that key is not `account_id`  you can not access it with `account_id`.

Comment: I know how to get a single document, but how would you go about getting an array of documents back with an `account_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view with a mapper like this:

```
function(doc){
    emit([doc.account_id], null)
}
```

Then you can call the view with `startkey=[account_id,]&endkey=[account_id,{}]&include_docs=true`, where account_id is replaced with the id you want to get the documents for.

A good example is documented [here](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html) under "find many".

You could also just use `key=[account_id]`

I tend to always use arrays and both startkey and endkey, but it's up to you.